# Boost unit test case for fixed point addition

Tags: c++, loops, boost, types

hello all i am new to c++, here i need to do a boost test for a fixed point addition of my header file. It is done by the following code.

```
 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( add )
    {
        double a=(std::numeric_limits<fpml::fixed_point<short, 8> >::min)(); 
        double b=(std::numeric_limits<fpml::fixed_point<short, 8> >::max)(); 

        for (double x=a; x<b; ++x)
        {
            for (double y=a; y<b; ++y)
            {
                fpml::fixed_point<int, 16> xx = x;
                fpml::fixed_point<int, 16> yy = y;

                BOOST_CHECK( (fpml::fixed_point<int, 16>)(x+y) == xx+yy );
            }
        }
    }
```

i just need to know what is the hapenning inside the code,
A class template `fpml::fixed_point<short, 8>`  with limits of `short_min` is assigned to `double function a` and the same class template `fpml::fixed_point<short, 8>` with limits of `short_max` is assigned to `double function b`?

what is the happening in the `for loop` is it looping from minimum value of short to maximum value of short?

can someone please explain what is happening in the for lopp and how addition is done and checked

Comment: @ForEveRTo the double a and doube b is some values are assigned? or only limits are assigned? please explain this alone, i understood the for loop part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is `traits-type`. Somewhere in code, there is specialization for `fmpl::fixed_point<T, int>`. Then `a` == min value of type `fmpl::fixed_point<short, 8>` and `b` == max value of this type. For loop checks, that in range a to b for all pairs of `a` and `b`, `fmpl::fixed_point (a + b)` == sum of `fmpl::fixed_point(a)` and `fmpl::fixed_point(b)`.

Comment: so a will be assigned -32767(short_min) and b will be assigned 32767(short_max)?

Comment: @Rd7 If in `std::numeric_limits<fmpl::fixed_point>::min and max` returns such values - then yes.

Comment: @forEverThank you n actually i have a problem, i know all the therotical information of c++ like what is a function, what is a loop etc,. but when i see it in the code, i cannot follow the logic flow, what should i do to improve this?

Comment: another small doubt, for example if my `fmpl::fixed_point<short, 8>` is a integer type, so what will be assigned for my `a` will it assign `min limit` of `int` or `short`?

Comment: @Rd7 what? `fmpl::fixed_point` can't be integer type, since it's template class.

Comment: so `fmpl::fixed_point`is a template class having the member of type short ?

Comment: @Rd7 why? `fmpl::fixed_point` is template type with 2 parameters. Why you can't find it in YOUR code?

Comment: yes yes i found it, thank you.  I have a problem, i know all the therotical information of c++ like what is a function, what is a loop etc,. but when i see it in the code, i cannot follow the logic flow, what should i do to improve this?